# Using ActionCable to refresh a page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I built a support dashboard in rails 4 to help the support team monitor the health and timing of files being delivered by our clients.

I would like to transition this application to rails 5 and take advantage of ActionCable to make the app real time.

Every single example of ActionCable I can find is just some Chat application or a super specific implementation using devise, I cannot find any general tutorials examples that show how to "force" a refresh of a page when new data becomes available. So when the file gets scanned and the data goes in refresh the page or in a more advanced setup append a partial (which is a table row) to the top of the table.

So what I am getting at here is does anyone know of a general tutorial for ActionCable that is simply refreshing a page using ActiveRecord as a trigger or if such a thing is possible yet?

Comment: While waiting for an answer you can look at rendering partials in the actioncable channel to replace sections on your dashboard

Comment: @charles-spivey did you able to finds any useful links or content for this? I'm trying to do exactly same thing and all I found was chat apps. I'm building a dashboard POC with rails 5 + Actioncable.